# IndexError: indices are out-of-bounds

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter

hello every one when i run this part of code i got an error i don't no why its happened updating my packages or a mistakes in my for loop thanks to every body who wants to solve my problem.

here is the code

```
    %%capture
final = dict()
final['timeofday'] = []
final['image'] = []
final['name'] = []
final['location'] = []
final['price'] = []
final['rating'] = []
final['category'] = []

for i in range(1,(end_date - begin_date).days+2):
    for j in range(2):
        final['timeofday'].append('Morning')
    for j in range(2):
        final['timeofday'].append('Evening')

for i in range(len(final['timeofday'])): 
    if i%4 == 0: 
        final = top_recc(with_url, final)
    else:
        final = find_closest(with_url, final['location'][-1],final['timeofday'][i], final)
```

and give me below errors:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:1482, in _iLocIndexer._get_list_axis(self, key, axis)
   1481 try:
-> 1482     return self.obj._take_with_is_copy(key, axis=axis)
   1483 except IndexError as err:
   1484     # re-raise with different error message

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py:3716, in NDFrame._take_with_is_copy(self, indices, axis)
   3709 """
   3710 Internal version of the `take` method that sets the `_is_copy`
   3711 attribute to keep track of the parent dataframe (using in indexing
   (...)
   3714 See the docstring of `take` for full explanation of the parameters.
   3715 """
-> 3716 result = self.take(indices=indices, axis=axis)
   3717 # Maybe set copy if we didn't actually change the index.

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py:3703, in NDFrame.take(self, indices, axis, is_copy, **kwargs)
   3701 self._consolidate_inplace()
-> 3703 new_data = self._mgr.take(
   3704     indices, axis=self._get_block_manager_axis(axis), verify=True
   3705 )
   3706 return self._constructor(new_data).__finalize__(self, method="take")

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py:897, in BaseBlockManager.take(self, indexer, axis, verify)
    896 n = self.shape[axis]
--> 897 indexer = maybe_convert_indices(indexer, n, verify=verify)
    899 new_labels = self.axes[axis].take(indexer)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexers\utils.py:292, in maybe_convert_indices(indices, n, verify)
    291     if mask.any():
--> 292         raise IndexError("indices are out-of-bounds")
    293 return indices

IndexError: indices are out-of-bounds

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [8], in <cell line: 16>()
     16 for i in range(len(final['timeofday'])): 
     17     if i%4 == 0: 
---> 18         final = top_recc(with_url, final)
     19     else:
     20         final = find_closest(with_url, final['location'][-1],final['timeofday'][i], final)

File ~\Desktop\Intelligent-Travel-Recommendation-System-master\attractions_recc.py:114, in top_recc(with_url, final)
    112 i=0
    113 while(1):
--> 114     first_recc = with_url.iloc[[i]]
    115     if(first_recc['name'].values.T[0] not in final['name']):
    116         final['name'].append(first_recc['name'].values.T[0])

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:967, in _LocationIndexer.__getitem__(self, key)
    964 axis = self.axis or 0
    966 maybe_callable = com.apply_if_callable(key, self.obj)
--> 967 return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:1511, in _iLocIndexer._getitem_axis(self, key, axis)
   1509 # a list of integers
   1510 elif is_list_like_indexer(key):
-> 1511     return self._get_list_axis(key, axis=axis)
   1513 # a single integer
   1514 else:
   1515     key = item_from_zerodim(key)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:1485, in _iLocIndexer._get_list_axis(self, key, axis)
   1482     return self.obj._take_with_is_copy(key, axis=axis)
   1483 except IndexError as err:
   1484     # re-raise with different error message
-> 1485     raise IndexError("positional indexers are out-of-bounds") from err

IndexError: positional indexers are out-of-bounds
```

IndexError: indices are out-of-bounds

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

IndexError: positional indexers are out-of-bounds

source: https://github.com/sachinnpraburaj/Intelligent-Travel-Recommendation-System/blob/master/get_att_recc.ipynb

Comment: Why do beginners think they can summarize the error?  Show the **whole** thing!

Comment: in `top_recc` the `i` index is too large.

Comment: @hpaulj ok what should i do

Comment: Hi @MahdiKarblaee, when an index of an array, list or any iterable object, is out of bounds. Out of bounds simply means index doesn't fall in the range of the length of the iterator. Try doing a len(myobject) and see if the index(where the error is occurring) is less than the length. Thank You.